# Scrapy: how to write scrapes to json while using Windows 7 command line

Tags: python, json, windows, scrapy

In Python, I have been using Scrapy to scrape a website.

However, I am using Windows 7, and I think it is responsible for these two commands in my settings.py file resulting writing an empty csv file:

```
FEED_FORMAT = 'csv'
FEED_URI = 'my_csv.csv'
```

I have found that I can't pipe my scrapes out to a file unless I use something like

`scrapy crawl my_spider > my_csv.csv`

So unfortunately, I'm getting no love from the `FEED_FORMAT` and `FEED_URI` item exporters, and to make things a little more difficult, I would love to have my scrapes in json format...

I'm bracing for the reality that I am going to have to jump through some major hoops.  Has anyone had a similar issue, and found a good workaround?

How can I output my scrape as json, using the Windows command line?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `FEED_FORMAT` or `FEED_URI` and try `scrapy crawl my_spider -t json -o my_json.json`

Comment: Would you care to elaborate into a full-fledged answer?